# Как сделать SELECT с MYSQL не с начала

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется скрипт который берет с БД по одному значению и пробегается от начала и до конца.

Есть ли возможность в БД начать не с начала?

т.е. мне нужно начать выборку значений с 350й записи, мне не нужно, что бы выборка шла с самого начала.

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас неверная логика выполнения. В чем смысл этого действия?

Comment: @Smithson, Как это в чем? У вас несколько *лярдов записей в таблице. При обращении к таблице вы будете все сразу просматривать, или же подгружать по "чуть-чуть"?

Comment: Лично я буду писать условие выборки, а не подгружать по чуть-чуть.

Comment: @Smithson, окей, как вы выведете все вопросы с данного ресурса? Вот мы открываем главную страничу SO и видим внизу пагинацию со страницами со всеми вопросами

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 50 OFFSET 350;
```

А вообще не стесняйтесь сначала воспользоваться поиском.

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from table limit 349, 200
```

Выдаст с 350 строки 200 записей (нумерация в таком случае идёт с 0-й строки, поэтому 349).

Вообще почитайте про [`limit`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1): SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15